# Https for prometheus with self-signed ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, prometheus, dock

Trying to get up SSL for prometheus (started via docker). I generated key and crt myself using open ssl. Pair: key and crt works ok.
when I execute this command on my host:

```sh
openssl s_server -cert prometheus.crt -key prometheus.key
```

It's saying "ACCEPT"

Here is my Dockerfile for prometheus container:
https://pastebin.com/4wGtCGp6
When I build image and start it, it's saying:
level=error ts=2021-09-24T20:44:11.649Z caller=stdlib.go:105 component=web caller="http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:50458" msg="remote error: tls: bad certificate"
кричит постоянно

In the web.yml I configure SSL in a following way:

```sh
tls_server_config:
  cert_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.crt
  key_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.key
```

In the prometheus.yml I configure SSL in a following way:

```sh
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.crt
      cert_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.crt
      key_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.key
```

What could be the reason of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's self-signed, you shouldn't need a CA file, so try deleting that line in the `tls_config` and restarting the container.

I know this is old, so apologies if it's bad to answer an old question. Feel free to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell prometheus which config files to use.
You can define them in the docker run command as follows

```bash
docker run -d prom/prometheus \
  --name prometheus \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml
```

Change the paths of the files according to your environment.